# Install XGBoost on EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-ec2, xgboost

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to install XGBoost on EC2. I have set up the EC2 instance and installed Numpy/SKlearn like this:

```
sudo yum -y install gcc-c++ python27-devel atlas-sse3-devel lapack-devel
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.11.2.tar.gz
tar xzf virtualenv-1.11.2.tar.gz 
python27 virtualenv-1.11.2/virtualenv.py sk-learn
. sk-learn/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

I have a working implementation of xgb on my workstation, which I installed via: pip install xgboost. But when I try this on the EC2, I get the error:

```
(sk-learn)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-221 ~]$ pip install xgboost
Downloading/unpacking xgboost
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xgboost (from versions: 0.4a15, 0.4a22, 0.4a28, 0.4a26, 0.4a25, 0.4a30, 0.4a12, 0.4a14, 0.4a23, 0.4a19, 0.4a29, 0.4a21, 0.4a13, 0.4a18, 0.4a24, 0.4a20, 0.4a27)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for xgboost
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ec2-user/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized, I needed to upgrade pip first:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

I will leave the question for others though. Thanks!